# GWT default place automatically in browser history?

Tags: java, gwt

Is it normal that the default place is automatically in the browser history at the first position? When I initially call my application I have the possibility to use the back button in my browser. Then the browser jumps to my default page which is my error page. Is this the normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The history is handled by the browser. You have no chance to change it.

Maybe you can change your application and use a dialogbox to show your errors, so no entry will be down in the browser history.

Comment: I know that I can't change the browser's behavior. But I can change the behavior of GWT.
A dialogbox for errors is nothing I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Read the gwt documentation about history.
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html

Look at:
 History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler.....

Then you need to set history tokens in each view.

With this you can change the browser back button behaviour and how you navigate in the app.

Comment: In the documentation is nothing written about the default page.